# #audioplayers package Not Working in Flutter Linux Desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

When building an application, the build failed with the following message.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/audioplayers_linux/linux/CMakeLists.txt:24 (pkg_check_modules)


Building Linux application...                                           
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

Tried running the application in Linux and got the above-mentioned message and then the build failed. Expecting it to build as it was built in mobile app

Answer (score 1):

Our team also encountered the error with **CMakeLists.txt:24**. We found in our CMakeLists.txt that the issue were missing gstreamer packages. After we installed them compiling worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

It still had issues during runtime (on unbuntu 22.0x) but it turned out, that we needed to "install the Flutter SDK manually" (instead of using snap) as detailed here:

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers_linux#setup-for-linux